# Вычислить сумму всех чисел массива, php массивы

Tags: php, массивы, min

все по порядку:№1

```
     $arr1 = [];

      for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){

      $arr1[$i] = mt_rand(0,10);

       }
```

здесь созданы случайные 10 массива с случайными значениями 
 дальше идем №2

```
        $arr2=[];

       for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
       {

        $arr2[$i]= [];

        for($j=0; $j<$arr1[$i]; $j++){

        $arr2[$i][$j]=mt_rand(0, 10);
       }
         }
```

здесь создаються массивы от элементов первого массива дальше :№3

```
        $max=$min = $arr2[0];

         for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
        if($max < $arr2[$i]){
            $max = $arr2[$i];
        }
        if ($min > $arr2[$i]){
            $min = $arr2[$i];
        } 

        }

        print_r($max); print_r($min);
```

Нахожу максимальное и минимальное значения из массива №2
вот вывод  из двух массивов:

Array
         (

[0] => 2

[1] => 9

[2] => 6

[3] => 5

[4] => 1

[5] => 9

[6] => 5

[7] => 2

[8] => 5

)

Array

(

[0] => 0

[1] => 1

теперь нужно сложить из второго массива min  все числа:

```
          $min = $arr2[0];
          $sum = 0;
         for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
          if($min > $arr2[$i]){
             $min = $arr2[$i];
            } 
            #$sum += $arr2[$i];
            }
             #echo $sum;
```

! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types

подскажите как правильно вычислять элементы данного массива

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас там косяки уже на шаге 3. Но в любом случае, если требуется сложить числа, то зачем вы какие то проверки и сравнения делаете?

Comment: @teran а разве максимум и минимум не так находят ? просто я с минимумс же должен как то или там просто указать переменную $min

Comment: ну у вас же есть уже массив минимумов, зачем еще что то искать и сравнивать. просто просуммируйте его. или что?

Comment: @teran да все правильно как суммировать та ? я чет вообще отупел

Comment: Если у вас `$min` это массив, то очевидно `$sum =0; foreach($min as $v) $sum += $v`; Вы почему то складываете не минимумы а `arr2[i]`, хотя это сами по себе массивы, и их нельзя приплюсовать к числу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас, конечно,задача учебная, чтобы посчитать это все руками и циклами, но в целом можно решить ее следующим образом. Я так понимаю, что вам надо создать массив из 10 рандомных чисел. Затем сделать двумерным массив, где число элементов на втором уровне будет равно случайному числу из предыдущего массива (*мелькала такая задача недавно уже*). Затем найти массив минимумов и максимумов для него. А затем посчитать сумму этих минимумов. ?

с помощью функций для работы с массивами решение может быт таким:

```
function fill($len){
    $result = [];
    while($len--) $result[] = mt_rand(1, 10);
    return $result;
}

$first  = fill(10);
$second = array_map("fill", $first);
$min    = array_map('min', $second);
$max    = array_map('max', $second);
$minSum = array_sum($min);


print_r( compact('first', 'second', 'min', 'max', 'minSum'));
```

Для длины `3`:

```
Array (
    [first] => Array (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )    
    [second] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [0] => 9
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 3
                )    
            [1] => Array (
                    [0] => 5
                )    
        )    
    [min] => Array (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )    
    [max] => Array (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 5
        )    
    [minSum] => 8
)
```

В принципе если надо все это сгенерить и посчитать только сумму минимумов, то все можно вписать в одну строку

```
$smin = array_sum(array_map('min', array_map("fill", fill(10));
```

Comment: @Doom'sday лабораторную вы так не сдадите :)

Comment: не это я для себя искал :) но спасибо конечно я да функций еще не дошел) но это круто)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка у вас возникает потому, что `$arr2[$i]` - это массив. Вот как вы его инициализируете `$arr2[$i]= [];`
Естественно сложение числа и массива - это не та операция, которая имеет какой либо смысл.

Comment: там еще на этапе поиска минимумов шляпа какая то `$max < $arr2[$i]`, где `max` это массив